# linphone set SIP to SIP talk?

Tags: iphone, ip, voip, sip

I'm trying to add sip to sip talk to our VoIP app, which is using linphone background. Basically, I would like to add a function that lets users to talk between each other thru their VoIP accounts.

Does anyone have any experience about that?

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference:
That's what SIP is for: endpoints communicating.

All the intermediaries (proxies, B2BUAs, registrars, SBCs, STUN, etc) are only added to facilitate this or provide extra functionality.

As long as you know the routable IP address or domain name of a SIP endpoint which is operational at the time, have at least one common codec, etc, you can call them directly without any of the in-between stuff.